# No output to console with println on maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, netbeans

So whenever I build and test my maven package i am not getting an output and the program auto closes, I have tried this on Eclipse and Netbeans and still no heed, thanks in advance and the code is below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Boolean end = false;
    while(end = false){
    System.out.println("Enter your command(for list of commands press h): ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String command = scanner.nextLine();
    if(command == "h"){
        System.out.println("start   starts basic program");
        System.out.println("start1  starts twitter based program(in development)");
        System.out.println("api     sets api");
        System.out.println("time     sets check time");

    }else if( command == "start"){
        mainmethod();
    }else if(command == "time"){

    }else if( command == "end"){
                end = true;
            }
    }


}
```

Comment: Maven builds the project and packages unless you have specified a Main class as it run configuration which I believe might be missing in your case.

Comment: Please put your pom.xml as well for reference. Thanks.

Comment: `while(end == false)`  : use `==` instead of `=` to check boolean equality
<br/>Also use `if(command.equals("h")`  instead of `command == "h"` to check string equality.

Answer (score 0):

your code means:

```
while(false){.....}
```

Please change from:

```
while(end = false){
......
}
```

into:

```
while(end == false){
......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's "==" rather than "=".end == false